# Lucene document object duplicate its unchanged fields

Tags: java, lucene

I have been working on lucene since about 1 years and suddenly today I figured out something weird about it.

I was updating my indexing using the normal lucene mechanism of fetching the document and deleting old document and then reindexing the document.
So 
1. Fetched the document to update from lucene index and maintained this doc in a list 
2. Removed the document from index.
3. Using the doc from list updated some of it field and then re-indexed this document.

But when I found that this updated document that was indexed were having duplicate values for the original document field.

Like suppose there was a field id:1 and I didnt updated this field and updated the other content from the document and then index this doc.
I found that this id:1 was appearing two times in the same document. And even further if i reindex the same document the same field will get created those many time under single document.

How should I get rid of this duplication?

Answer (score 1):

I have to make some modification for the document that was re-indexed. Means that document I fetched from the indexed, using that I took out all the fields and then created a new fresh document and added those field to that document and then re-indexed this new document, which got indexed properly without any duplication.
Was not able to find the cause but the document fetched from index was having docId and due to this when it was re-index internally some duplication might be taking place which must have cause the problem.